# Merge two table

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

I have two tables, one table has FROM_SERIAL, TO_SERIAL and TRANSACTION_DATE. And another table has SERIAL_NO and ACTIVATION_DATE. I want to merge both two table within a particular range.

Example:

First Table

```
   FROM_SERIAL        TO_SERIAL       TRANSACTION_DATE
   10003000100        10003000500     22-APR-19
   10003001100        10003001300     25-MAY-19
   10005002001        10005002500     30-AUG-19
```

Second Table

```
   SERIAL_NO        ACTIVATION_DATE
   10003000150      30-APR-19
   10005002300      01-OCT-19
```

Expecting Table

```
   FROM_SERIAL        TO_SERIAL       SERIAL_NO       ACTIVATION_DATE
   10003000100        10003000500     10003000150      30-APR-19
   10005002001        10005002500     10005002300      01-OCT-19
```

I want to merge both tables in the above scenario.

The code may be Oracle or Python, it doesn't matter.

Comment: See `pandas.merge` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas solution:

```
df = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df2.assign(a=1), on='a', how='outer')

df = df[df['SERIAL_NO'].between(df['FROM_SERIAL'], df['TO_SERIAL'])]
df = df.drop(['a','TRANSACTION_DATE'], 1)
print (df)
   FROM_SERIAL    TO_SERIAL    SERIAL_NO ACTIVATION_DATE
0  10003000100  10003000500  10003000150       30-APR-19
5  10005002001  10005002500  10005002300       01-OCT-19
```

But if large data better is use some oracle solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    t1.from_serial, 
    t1.to_serial,
    t2.serial_no,
    t2.activation_date
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.serial_no >= t1.from_serial AND t2.serial_no < t1.to_serial
```

You may ajust the inequalities as you wish. Beware that, if a given `serial_no` in `table2` belongs to more than one range in `table1`, they will all match and you will get duplicated `table1` records in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Join with `between`.

```
SQL> with
  2  tfirst (from_serial, to_serial) as
  3    (select 3000100, 3000500 from dual union all
  4     select 3001100, 3001300 from dual union all
  5     select 5002001, 5002500 from dual
  6    ),
  7  tsecond (serial_no, activation_date) as
  8    (select 3000150, date '2019-04-30' from dual union all
  9     select 5002300, date '2019-10-01' from dual
 10    )
 11  select a.from_serial,
 12    a.to_serial,
 13    b.serial_no,
 14    b.activation_date
 15  from tfirst a join tsecond b on b.serial_no between a.from_serial and a.to_serial;

FROM_SERIAL  TO_SERIAL  SERIAL_NO ACTIVATION
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    5002001    5002500    5002300 01.10.2019
    3000100    3000500    3000150 30.04.2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it using numpy broadcast feature like below. Explanation in comment

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('10003000100', '10003000500', '22-APR-19'), ('10003001100', '10003001300', '25-MAY-19'), ('10005002001', '10005002500', '30-AUG-19')], columns=('FROM_SERIAL', 'TO_SERIAL', 'TRANSACTION_DATE'))
df2 = df = pd.DataFrame([('10003000150', '30-APR-19'), ('10005002300', '01-OCT-19')], columns=('SERIAL_NO', 'ACTIVATION_DATE'))


## 'df1[["FROM_SERIAL"]]'' is a column vector of size m and 'df2["SERIAL_NO"].values' is row 
## vector of size n then broad cast will result array of shape m,n which is 
## result of comparing each pair of m and n
compare = (df1[["FROM_SERIAL"]].values<df2["SERIAL_NO"].values) & (df1[["TO_SERIAL"]].values>df2["SERIAL_NO"].values)

mask = np.arange(len(df1)*len(df2)).reshape(-1, len(df2))[compare]

pd.concat([df1.iloc[mask//len(df2)].reset_index(drop=True), df2.iloc[mask%len(df2)].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Comment: I tried ur code but it is not matching correctly, I think an error in "Transpose"

Comment: @ShulazShan sorry my bad, indexing was working only for sorted data, I have corrected the code now